# Ubuntu Server 22.04 will not install on an Intel S2600CO motherboard

Tags: server, grub2, 22.04

I am trying to load Ubuntu Server 22.04 on a S2600CO motherboard with 128GB of RAM and 16TB of storage. Another 16TB is used for files from my Windows desktop.

When I get to putting a name to the server I receive an error asking to start over with a new installer. I look and see that it is trying to install GRUB and that is where I encounter the problem.

Is there a work around for this so I can get it installed and deal with issues later on? At this point I can't get to a shell to do any searches and nothing is written to any drives as far as I can tell.

Is there away to load Ubuntu without it attaching to a cloud image? I believe that is the problem even though I am wired.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install? UEFI or BIOS? <- It's modern hardware so it should be UEFI therefore always prefer UEFI/GPT. Also avoid installing OSes in arrays, prefer a small independent SSD for that.

Comment: How big is the drive, where you intend to install? Are you intending to install into the whole drive? Or are you creating several partitions? Is it feasible for you to install into a small independent SSD (say 128 or 256 GiB)?

Comment: Start over and follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). Do not skip steps. If you still have problems, reference the tutorial when asking. As currently written, your details are unclear and ambiguous. If you follow the tutorial you can tell us exactly what step you are having problems with. If you are getting error messages, you need to provide the error message. The entire purpose of errors is to provide information about the problem, so please be specific and detailed.